# Pandas merge two columns into Json

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like below

```
    Col1    Col2
0     a     apple
1     a     anar
2     b     ball
3     b     banana
```

I am looking to output json which outputs like

```
{ 'a' : ['apple', 'anar'], 'b' : ['ball', 'banana'] }
```

Comment: aren't they outputting the same thing?

Comment: not, different. dictionary vs json.

Comment: I just went by seeing the output :)

Comment: @anky_91 - yes, but it is not json, only looks like json.

Comment: @garg10may - json is string, so `to_json` return `json string`, but `to_dict` retutn dictionary. Answer was modify for difference.

Comment: thx. yes understood the difference, though both have been very prompt and helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and last convert `Series` to `json` by [`Series.to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_json.html):

```
j = df.groupby('Col1')['Col2'].apply(list).to_json()
print (j)
{"a":["apple","anar"],"b":["ball","banana"]}
```

If want write `json` to file:

```
s = df.groupby('Col1')['Col2'].apply(list)
s.to_json('file.json')
```

Check difference:

```
j = df.groupby('Col1')['Col2'].apply(list).to_json()
d = df.groupby('Col1')['Col2'].apply(list).to_dict()

print (j)
{"a":["apple","anar"],"b":["ball","banana"]}
print (d)
{'a': ['apple', 'anar'], 'b': ['ball', 'banana']}

print (type(j))
<class 'str'>

print (type(d))
<class 'dict'>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) `'Col1'` and [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) list to `'Col2'` and convert [`to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html), Use:

```
df.groupby('Col1')['Col2'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

**Output**:

```
{'a': ['apple', 'anar'], 'b': ['ball', 'banana']}
```